# Reverse String without using StringBuffer.reverse()

Tags: java, garbage-collection, stringbuffer

What is the problem in following example? what happens if millions of Char in the String to be Reversed?

```
public static String reverseUsingStringBuffer(String source) {
    if(source == null || source.isEmpty()){
        return source;
    }       
    StringBuffer reverse = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i = source.length() -1; i>=0; i--){
        reverse.append(source.charAt(i));
    }

    return reverse.toString();
}
```

Is following better approach? (beside using api method). What is the good approach for huge String?

```
public static String reverse(String source) {
    if(source == null || source.isEmpty()){
        return source;
    }       
    String reverse = "";
    for(int i = source.length() -1; i>=0; i--){
        reverse = reverse + source.charAt(i);
    }

    return reverse;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, It was replaced by StringBuilder ten years ago.  Why don't you try it?  You should see the difference almost immediately.

Comment: Technically, this does not use `StringBuffer#reverse`: `return new StringBuilder(source).reverse().toString();`.

Comment: @assylias Why did you delete that anwer? I was about to upvote, as it is the only sane one.

Comment: @Navin: No, mine is sane, too. And so am I. :D:D For sure, his is the simplest.

Comment: @maaartinus fair enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already said, the `String` approach is pretty bad. Using `StringBuffer` is much better, but there's no reason for this rather obsolete class, when `StringBuilder` can do the same faster.

Even simpler and faster in this case is to use an array:

```
char[] result = new char[source.length];
for(int i = 0; i < source.length(); ++i) result[source.length() - 1 - i] = source.charAt(i);
return new String(result);
```

This allocates no garbage at all.... except for the `char[]`, but this is unavoidable as String is immutable and the sharing constructor is package-private (for a good reason).

Note that usually there's absolutely no need to optimize that hard.

Comment: Surely you mean `i<len`. Also, `source.charAt(i);` instead of `source.charAt[i];`

Comment: @Navin: Fixed, thanks. This all comes from copy&paste, as usual.

Comment: Manual hoisting of `len` is rather superfluous since it will be done by the JIT anyway :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, I rather wanted to keep the expression short... which was actually unnecessary as it's short anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, the first approach is better because it will internally manage your buffers for you. Don't try to outsmart the compiler. Why didn't you append the entire source in one line, which will properly allocate your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The first one. In the second you use "string = string + string" and this creates one object every time you use "+". I'd sugest StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is better, StringBuffer is mutable and using string = string+string decrease performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in place as well.

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
   char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
   for(int i = 0, j = chars.length - 1; i < chars.length / 2; i++, j--) {
     char c = chars[i];
     chars[i] = chars[j];
     chars[j] = c;
   }
   return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: isn't `chars` an extra buffer?